# Postgis function is not unique

Tags: sql, postgresql, drupal, postgis, cartaro

I'm trying out [cartaro](http://cartaro.org/), and I get an error when trying to create a spatial object.  The error mesage is

```
Unable to parse WKT: POLYGON((2323165.9017765 -3715665.1528316,2325153.2645117 -3715818.0268882,2323471.6498896 -3717652.5155667,2323165.9017765 -3715665.1528316))
```

Looking in the postgres logs, I see that the database error is

```
ERROR:  function st_geometrytype(unknown) is not unique at character 8
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
STATEMENT:  SELECT ST_GeometryType('POLYGON((2323165.9017765 -3715665.1528316,2325153.2645117 -3715818.0268882,2323471.6498896 -3717652.5155667,2323165.9017765 -3715665.1528316))'), ST_IsValid('POLYGON((2323165.9017765 -3715665.1528316,2325153.2645117 -3715818.0268882,2323471.6498896 -3717652.5155667,2323165.9017765 -3715665.1528316))'), ST_IsValidReason('POLYGON((2323165.9017765 -3715665.1528316,2325153.2645117 -3715818.0268882,2323471.6498896 -3717652.5155667,2323165.9017765 -3715665.1528316))') as reason
```

If I try running a simplified version of the statement manually I get

```
# SELECT ST_GeometryType('POINT(10 10)');
ERROR:  function st_geometrytype(unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: SELECT ST_GeometryType('POINT(10 10)');
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

However,

```
# SELECT ST_GeometryType(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(10 10)'));
 st_geometrytype 
-----------------
 ST_Point
(1 row)
```

It looks like cartaro is getting the query wrong and omitting the `St_GeometryFromText`, but it seems odd that there would be such a blatant error in it.  Could it be something to do with the version of PostGIS I'm using (2.1.0), or is this really just a bug?

**EDIT**

```
# \df ST_GeometryType
                              List of functions
  Schema  |      Name       | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
----------+-----------------+------------------+---------------------+--------
 public   | st_geometrytype | text             | geometry            | normal
 topology | st_geometrytype | text             | tg topogeometry     | normal
(2 rows)
```

It looks like there are two functions that match that name, should one be removed?

Comment: \df ST_GeometryType ... what functions do you see listed?

Comment: I see two, one in public schema and one in topology.  Looks like that could be the problem!  But how do I solve it?  Can I delete one?

Comment: Sounds like you've installed the PostGIS extension to more than one schema, or have a manual install + an extension. Maybe a holdover from a previous PostGIS 1.x install?

Comment: No, its a new install, but I had an earlier problem installing the topology and I might have done something that's left behind the duplicates.

Comment: I just reinstalled it all, making sure at every step that there is only one `st_geometry_type` function.  But immediately after installing cartaro, the second appeared. It seems cartaro is somehow duplicating it.