# Weird error calling postgis function

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to solve a problem related to what appears to be duplicated functions in a postgis database (original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487940/postgis-function-is-not-unique)), but in my testing I'm getting something very odd happening.  I have installed a new postgres database in [openshift](http://openshift.redhat.com), activated the postgis extensions, and tried doing a transform twice.  The first time it worked, the second time it didn't.  Here is the full command line:

```
test=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION
test=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION
test=# SELECT ST_Transform('SRID=3857;POINT(-10000000 5200000)'::geometry,4326);
                    st_transform                    
----------------------------------------------------
 0101000020E6100000E0C1F1C2377556C0F04DCF5946214540
(1 row)

test=# SELECT ST_Transform('SRID=3857;POINT(-10000000 5200000)'::geometry,4326);
ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (-1e+07 5.2e+06 0): failed to load NAD27-83 correction file (-38)
test=#
```

I executed these commands straight after each other.  I also tried creating a new database a couple of times but got the same behaviour in each.  Why would it work once but not the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install package called 'proj-nad'

So 'yum install proj-nad'

Thats is.