# GeoDjango constructs faulty SQL query during testing

Tags: geodjango

One of my GeoDjango tests fails with a

````
ProgrammingError: function st_intersects(text, geometry) is not unique
LINE 1: ...NT(*) AS "__count" FROM "field" WHERE ST_Interse...```
````

I can't figure out why it is calling `st_intersects(text, geometry)` instead of `st_intersects(geometry, geometry)` seeing that it's defined as

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon

...

bbox_geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox.split(','))
return Field.objects.filter(geom__intersects=bbox_geom)
```

in my view where `bbox = '1,1,2,2'` or equivalent and `geom` is a `MultiPolygon`.

This happens only when testing as

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()

def test_bbox_filter_single_feature(self):
    response = self.client.get('/api/v1/fields/', {'bbox': '1,1,2,2'})

    ...
```

Calling this view in any other way (browser, Postman, `curl`) outside the testing environment does not generate this error.

Note: I've a similar view for a `Point` geometry which passes the test without a hitch.

What is different during testing that might cause this issue? Any thoughts on how to fix it? I'm running Django 1.11.11, PostgreSQL 9.5.4 and PostGIS 2.2.2

Comment: Can you add the output of: `print(Field.objects.filter(geom__intersects=bbox_geom).query)` ?

Comment: How are you running your tests? can you make sure the test database is deleted and rebuilt from scratch correctly (do not use `-k`/`--keep-db`) ?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487940/postgis-function-is-not-unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try `print Field.objects.filter(geom__intersects=bbox_geom).query`, you will see that the first argument supplied to `ST_Intersects` is your `Field.geom` field. Therefore, the database has a `Text` definition of `field.geom`.

There is something wrong with your migrations, which forget to define `Field.geom` as a Geometry. With *Django < 1.9* I would have thought of a forgotten `objects = manager.GeoManager` definition on you Model  class, but that's unnecessary since Django 1.9.

Comment: The migrations were indeed wrong. Django's `inspectdb` though the geo table to be of type `Text`. I changed it manually in `models.py` but didn't in the migrations. Thanks for the hint!